# d3.js Day Hour Heatmap loads on server restart, but disappears when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I have a very weird situation on my hands and I'm not sure how to fix it. I will say that I am new to Angular.js and D3.js so if you see a newb mistake, it's probably not a typo, it's me having done something wrong.

Anyways - I'm using Eclipse with m2e and tomcat plugins and running straight from the IDE. I'm trying to load a day/hour heatmap with example code I found here: [blocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084)

I made one small change, where instead of the d3.tsv call, I'm using d3.json and implementing a REST call to retrieve the json. The interesting part here is that whenever I restart the server and load the page, I see the heatmap as it is supposed to appear. However, if I refresh the page, it disappears. If I load the page in a new tab, it also will not appear.

**Strangely enough it does appear when I close and re-open the browser, but then disappears again later with refreshes and new tabs.**

Every time I refresh the page I can see the REST call being correctly called in the eclipse console. I can also see the JSON data appearing correctly in the javascript console on my browser. These things all happen correctly regardless of whether or not the heatmap appears.

Below is some of my code that I think will be relevant, feel free to ask for more snippets if necessary.

REST Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/heatmap", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody String getHeatMapValues(){
     return heatMapValues;
}
```

index.html

```
//Assume all standard javascript imports here are correct (the thing does work correctly at least once, and I'd have bigger errors anyways
<body>
     <div class="panel panel-default" ng-app="Hello" ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <div class="panel-heading">
               <h2 class="panel-title">VISUALIZATIONS</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="col-lg-10" style="border: 2px solid black">
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                       <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click=selectTab($index) ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == $index}">
                            <a data-target="#tab" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.id}}</a>
                       </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="tab-content">
                       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab" ng-include="tabs[selectedTab].template">
                       </div> 
                  </div>
              </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

script.js (yes, I'll break up the javascript code appropriately later, now i just want everything to work)

```
var app = angular.module('Hello', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function Hello($scope, $http) {
     $scope.tabs = [{id:"Main",template: "partials/main.html"},{id: "Clustering",template: "partials/clustering.html"}];
     $scope.selectedTab=0;
     $scope.selectTab = function(index){
          $scope.selectedTab = index;
     }
var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
      legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
      buckets = 9,
      colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
      days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
      times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];


  d3.json("/heatmap",
    function(error, data) {
      var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
          .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
          .range(colors);

      var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

      var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

      var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);

      heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

      heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; })
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend");

      legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + gridSize);
  });
}
```

partials/main.html

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

partials/clustering.html

```
<b>hi there</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. I was thinking this was an issue of state within D3. In reality the answer is much simpler.

Because I was only testing the chart, I put the d3 code inside my angular controller that will execute on startup. This was causing a race condition between the d3 script (which was searching for the div with id="chart") and the DOM which was still loading html.

I changed my app controller to contain this:

```
$scope.init = function(){
    //d3 chart script
}
```

I also changed main.html to look like this:

```
<div id="chart" data-ng-init="init()"></div>
```

Now it loads consistently every time!